# Which scope does an in-class-defined friend function belong to?

Tags: c++

```
class A {
    friend void f() {}
};

// void f() {}  // compile error: redifinition of 'void f()'

int main() {
    f();  // compile error: 'f' is not declared in this scope
}
```

As you can see in the above example, if `f` is called in `A`'s enclosing namespace scope, the compiler just can't find `f`, which gives me the idea that `f` is not in this scope.  But when an out-of-calss definition of a function with the same signature is added, the compiler issues an error of function redefinition, which gives me the opposite idea that `f` is actually in this scope.

So, I'm puzzled which scope an in-class-defined friend function belongs to.

Comment: That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the namespace containing the class.

However, if it's only declared in the class, then it's only available by argument-dependent lookup. So this would work, with the argument type `A` finding `f` in the surrounding namespace:

```
class A {
    friend void f(A) {}
};

int main() {
    f(A());    // OK: uses ADL
    ::f(A());  // Error: doesn't use ADL, and can't find the name without it
}
```

This is often used for overloaded operators, which can only be found by ADL anyway.

Your version would work if you declared, rather than redefined, the function at namespace scope.

```
void f();
```

Comment: iow, the friend definition injects the definition into the enclosing namespace, without making a declaration visible in that namespace?

Answer (score -3):

The friend function should only be declared, not defined, in the class. E.g. friend void f();

Comment: The friend function may well be defined inside the class, there's no rule against it (having already supassed any guidelines discouraging the use of `friend`).

Comment: You can define it inside or outside the class if you want to. Just not both, since there can only be one definition.