# The scope of in-class-defined friend function?

Tags: c++

A few days ago I asked a question about the scope of in-class-defined friend functions ([Which scope does an in-class-defined friend function belong to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581471/which-scope-does-an-in-class-defined-friend-function-belong-to)), and I get to know that the function is in the scope of the enclosing namespace but won't be searchable until explicitly declared outside the class (ADL is an exception).

Today I found some relevant statements in the C++ standard (section 11.3):

> A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class M {  
>     friend void f() { } // definition of global f, a friend of M,  
>                         // not the definition of a member function  
> };  
> —end example ]
> ```
>
> Such a function is implicitly `inline`. A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined. A friend function defined outside the class is not (3.4.1).

We can see that there are two scope-related statements here: **"has namespace scope"** and **"is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined"**.  I'm confused here.  If the former relates to my previous question ([Which scope does an in-class-defined friend function belong to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581471/which-scope-does-an-in-class-defined-friend-function-belong-to)), then what does the latter stand for?

Comment: AFAIK, it's about name lookup inside the friend function. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/046896a00ece8086)

Answer (score 1):

A "namespace-scope function" is a function that is a member of a namespace (i.e the "scope" here means the "home scope" of the function).

The later statement links to 3.4.1, which has to say

> Name lookup for a name used in the definition of a friend function (11.3) defined inline in the class granting friendship shall proceed as described for lookup in member function definitions.